# Referencing a Password protected external Excel Workbook in VBA without actually opening the workbook

Tags: vba, excel, external

I'm using Excel 2016. Basically, I have a Userform where the user enters data and submits it. This data gets stored in a **Table** in a worksheet present in an **external Workbook**. Upon click of a button I'll retrieve that data and print on a different Worksheet. Now I'm able to do all of these operations. The only problem is, in order to make changes to the external workbook I have to open it like this:

```
Public WBSource, WBTarget As Workbook

Set WBSource = Workbooks.Open("Source.xlsx")
```

I need this Workbook object in multiple functions, hence I've declared it public and set like this in **ThisWorkbook**'s **Open** event. I don't want to have the Source workbook to be opened every time I need to access this object.

1. Is there a way to link external Workbooks without actually opening
   the file ?
2. If Workbook & its worksheets are Password protected, how
   can I access them ?

Comment: once you opened it at the beginning of your macro and set it to "WBSource", you simply have to use "WBSource" reference to unprotect it and make desired changes

Comment: I do agree. But if some error occurs and the control goes to my Error Handler where I'm using 'End' after showing the error message, these objects are getting set to Empty. So I'll have to rebuild the link. Is there a way to just connect but not actually open the file ?

Comment: In short: 1: No. 2: You open it, that is how you access them. (You can manipulate a workbook without opening it in Excel, but then you will have to basically read the raw xlsx file using an SDK like Office OpenXML SDK or parsing it as an XML... Trust me, you don't want that.)

Comment: Oh that's bad :-( I have Masters for many parameters and have to access them many times. So I'll have to have all these Worksheets in the same Workbook if I don't want to open them again !!!

Comment: You should NEVER use "End" statement, and in any case just have your error handler set relevant variables back to what you need! Another possibility is having your external Workbook cells be filled with formulas that reference your working workbook so that after editing and saving the latter you can open the former and have its data refreshed.

Comment: What should I use in my Error Handler to stop execution of the code then ? I mean what's the equivalent of Exit in VBA ?

Comment: End Sub, nut just End.

Comment: End Sub/Function will stop executing that particular Sub/Function. But in some cases I'm calling a function based on the return value from the previous function call. And if there's an error in Function 1, control exists Function 1 and the next statement is call to Function 2 whose parameters are return values of Function 1......this throws an error too

Comment: you can add some boolean parameters in your function as well as error handling that have those boolean parameters set to "False" if the function throws any error and have the caller function adjust its behaviour correspondingly